# running a dart exe in chroot

Tags: dart, exe, chroot

I'm trying to run a dart compiled executable (`app.exe`) in a chroot.  Outside of chroot, I'm able to run it just fine, but when I attempt to run it in chroot, it looks like I'm just running the dart command and I simply get the `dart` usage:

```
Usage: dart [<vm-flags>] <dart-script-file> [<script-arguments>]
...
```

I've run `ldd app.exe` and added all the libraries and anything they loaded, though that doesn't seem to be enough to build the root directory.  Does anyone have a suggestion about how to find what I'm missing?

Comment: Consider filing an issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using `strip` on the binary? That causes the observed behavior.

Comment: This issue has been mentioned here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38731#issuecomment-538747829

Comment: No, it wasn't stripped.  I'm sure I just built it with default options.  I assume that the constructed binary dynamically loads some shared libraries, which is why ldd doesn't identify them.  I would also assume that loading the needed libraries fails with some generic error handler that simply prints out the dart usage producing the noted behavior.